# What are actually Jagang's powers?

Tags: the-sword-of-truth, terry-goodkind

In the series "Sword Of Truth" by Terry Goodkind, we read about Jagang the emperor of the Imperial Order in book 3, "Blood Of The Fold".

So far I read the books until "Naked Empire" and when I try to read some information by myself I always risk spoilers, so I ask here.

I understand he can just walk into any gifted one's thoughts and dreams.
In book 3, some sisters join forces to attack him, and it says he can escape that attack easily since he moves faster than thoughts.

However, in a later book, when he tries to attack Aydindril's palace he gets attacked by Zed who can almost easily kill him, without Jennsen's intervention.

So I am asking how vast his power really is, how come one wizard could deal with him but many powerful sisters of the dark could not.

I'm sure sooner or later he'll get defeated but I'm not there yet, so no spoilers, please.

Comment: This dream walking ability is really vicious, because Jagang can insert himself into one's mind without being noticed. There are a lot of applications, for instance he can (and does IIRC) spy through the eyes of unknowing gifted characters.

Comment: Jagang first appears in person in Book 3 - Blood of the Fold. in book 2, only the Imperial Order appears, as a mass of vicious killers, and the force that guides them is not revealed. Many believed then that it was the Keeper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#Jagang is a [Dream walker](https://sot.fandom.com/wiki/Dream_Walker)

<sub>The Blood Of The Fold, Chapter 18</sub>

> A dream walker can bend reality. Those with the gift can bring it to be.”

<sup>Chapter 27</sup>

> “I, on the other hand, am a dream walker. I use the time between fragments of thought, in that stillness when there is nothing, to do what I do. I slip in where no other can go.”

To sum up:

- A Dream walker can enter a mind of any person, gifted or not. Using that mind link, they can read minds of people they need, and give them orders (the target hears voices). The link is stronger with those gifted.

- Also, a dream walker may torture and kill using this mind link.
- Having entered a person's mind, the dream walker may choose to act, or sit and wait until the time comes. In the second case, he is virtually undetectable.

> There seems to be only one exception to the rule - Nicci, who for some reason always knew if Jagang had access to her mind. This is revealed in *Faith Of The Fallen*

- A dream walker is extremely rare, and has not been around for nearly 3000 years.

There is no defense against a dream walker, except:

- a magical barrier, that blocks all magic passing through it. **The Towers Of Perdition**, destroyed by Richard in *The Stone Of Tears*, were such a barrier. This was how the problem of the Dream walkers was solved in the past.
- **the Rahl bond**. Alric Rahl, one of Richard's ancestors, invented such a spell that protects himself and any gifted heir, and all that swear loyalty to them. The devotion (Master Rahl, guide us....) is a formal way to accept the terms of the bond, which is also expressed as "he is magic against magic, while we are steel against steel). However, loyalty to Master Rahl (the gifted Rahl) can be implied and never formally declared - see examples below.

Why was Zedd immune? **Because of the bond**, as he was ultimately loyal to Richard - The gifted heir of house Rahl. Same applies to all D'Harans, Verna, Warren and other people loyal to Richard (sometimes implicitly).

**Other examples**:

- In *Blood Of The Fold*, general Reibisch, the commander of D'Haran troops in Aydindrill, claims that he and his soldiers "stopped seeing nightmares" after making a devotion.
- Sisters of Light, led by Verna, spoke the words of devotion and Jagang stopped tormenting them (numerous examples through the books). When Richard's gift failed or was blocked (again many times throughout the books), Jagang re-appeared in their minds. Nathan had to act as a substitute Lord Rahl in Richard absence, because he was also a gifted Rahl.
- Sister Alessandra, former Sister of the Dark, converted back to the Light and accepted bond to Richard.
- Nicci was partially loyal

> until her catharsis in Book 6 (*Faith of the Fallen*) - this is why Jagang could not always enter her mind. After the end of FoTF, she became fully loyal, thus Jagang could not enter her mind.

Comment: More on the origin of Dream walkers is revealed in book 9 - read on!

Comment: Thanks for helping me get some order. So you're saying he can get hurt easily if he's caught unguarded by someone loyal to Rahl, and the reason all those sisters, launching an attack against him, did not succeed because he could, in an instant, get into their mind and stop the attack, since they're not loyal to Richard?

Comment: @MorZamir exactly.

Comment: Can't wait to continue book 9 now. I will upvote you tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

Jagang was a dream walker, with no other powers. He might not have admitted it before, but I suspect it was the reason why on many occasions throughout the books thought he didn't do x, y or z to them.

But in the second *[Chainfire Trilogy](https://sot.fandom.com/wiki/Chainfire_trilogy)* book, *[Phantom](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/43884.Phantom)*, Jagang admitted it, when two sisters of the dark brought him a captive in a Rada'Han. He told them, whilst the captive could hear, that he needed at least one of the sisters to stay alive and conscious while they were in 'to the tents', to keep the captive under control when they weren't there with him (as he couldn't).

His thought to the sisters only takes a micro-instant to send, and they take a micro instant to implement it, so it looks/seems as if he is doing it, but he couldn't without a conscious sister. So he demonstrates that he doesn't have 'The Gift'.

Indeed, with Goodkind's 'terrific writing and plot continuance skills', he himself seems to forget those very parameters which were stated by Jagang on one page, and continues his story without bothering with those details again. But they were laid out there in black and white.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. To hide a paragraph as a spoiler, just type `>!` at the start of it. :-)

Comment: Also, if you could [edit] this answer to include a direct quote of the text you alluded to in _Phantom_, that would be great.